# Nested Python class and access to parent's method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have following class in Python:

```
class SDK(object):
    URL = 'http://example.com'

    def checkUrl(self, url):
        #some code

    class api:
        def innerMethod(self, url):
            data = self.checkUrl(url)
            #rest of code
```

but when I try to access checkUrl from api, I get error. I try to call nested method by:

```
sdk = SDK()
sdk.api.innerMethod('http://stackoverflow.com')
```

Is there any simple way to call inner class methods, or (if not) structurize methods into inner objects? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Edit:
class code:

```
class SDK(object):
    def run(self, method, *param):
        pass

    class api:
        def checkDomain(self, domain):
            json = self.run('check', domain)
            return json
```

run code:

```
sdk = SDK()
result = sdk.api().checkDomain('stackoverflow.com')
```

Comment: Show the `rest of code`

Comment: Whats the use of the inner class?

Comment: @Daniel I am trying to structurize code, thats why I wanted to use inner class. Do you have any better idea?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any benefit to the `api` class over simply defining a method `SDK.checkDomain`.

Comment: I suggest you do this with modules, not inner classes.

Comment: @dease: try to find parts of your class, that can be really seperated in a own class on module level.

Comment: Any suggestions how to separate such parts into modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SDK` class is not a parent of the `api` class in your example, i.e. `api` does not inherit from `SDK`, they are merely nested.

Therefore the `self` object in your `api.innerMethod` method is only an instance of the `api` class and doesn't provide access to methods of the `SDK` class.

I strongly recommend getting more knowledgeable about object-oriented programming concepts and grasp what the issue is here. It will help you tremendously.

As for using modules to achieve something along these lines, you can, for example, pull everything from the `SDK` class to `sdk.py` file, which would be the `sdk` module.

sdk.py:

```
URL = 'http://example.com'

def checkUrl(url):
    #some code

class api:
    def innerMethod(self, url):
        data = checkUrl(url)
        #rest of code
```

main.py:

```
import sdk

api = sdk.api()
api.innerMethod('http://stackoverflow.com')
```

Or you may go even further and transform `sdk` to a package with `api` being a module inside it.

See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html for details on how to use modules and packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method to act as a classmethod, you have to tell python about it:

```
class SDK:
    class api:
         @classmethod
         def foo(cls):
                 return 1
```

Then you have access like

```
SDK.api.foo()
```

Depending on what you're trying to do, this smells kind of un-pythonic. If it's just the namespace you care about, you'd typically use a module.